# C++ Accessing and Manipulating 2D Pointer Array from within get function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, pointers

I am making a battleships game for my coursework, and I have run into some problems with the get functions in one of the classes I am using. The basic idea of my game is to create a 2D 10X10 array, called grid, filled with null pointers to represent the board. I have created 2 classes, Board and Ship. The grid array is of type Ship, and I use an algorithm to fill the array with Ships randomly. I use the Board class to access the grid array and the hits array (which I use to track hits).

However I cannot figure out how the getShips function can return the grid array. The hits array is just booleans so that was easy enough, but I am not proficient enough at C++ to make the getShips function properly return the grid array, which is a Ship pointer type. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
class Board
{

    private:

    Ship *grid[10][10];

    bool hits[10][10];

    public:
     // get functions

    Ship *getShips()
    { 
    return grid; 
    }

    bool getHits()
    {
    return hits;
    }
};
```

I was also wondering if it would be possible to manipulate the array in other functions by calling the `getShips` function. Something like:

```
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
  {
     for (int y=0; y<10; y++)
     {
       board.getShips()[x][y]=nullptr;
     }    
  }
```

Comment: Aren't ship supposed to take several squares? Some stuff aren't correct in your code. If you can give more details about how it's supposed to work I would gladly give you an answer.

Comment: Yes, I left out the code that places the ships, but basically I have a subclass for each ship with a different length value and a function that fills several spaces in the array with a Ship pointer, depending on the ships length. The placing algorithm was tested and working, but to include the Hits array as well as the Grid array I had to rewrite and include them both in the Board class, which is where this problem sprang up.

Comment: If anyone wants more to go on, or would like to see where this section of code fits into the whole program, the whole code is available on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/sRS8k75y

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First I would modify the getShips and getHits functions. To have something like that :

```
Ship *getShips(int x, int y){ return grid[x+y*10]; }
bool getHits(int x, int y){return hits[x+y*10];}
```

That way you'll simplify your code and avoid some errors.
When you declare a multidimensional array like you do with

```
Ship *grid[10][10];

bool hits[10][10];
```

you're basically declaring pointers to pointers to pointers to ships.

I would try to use a minimum amount of pointers if you're writing in C++. Try to use the stl containers instead. They do automatic memory management for you which may save you some time down the road.

Comment: I think he wants to return all ships using the get ships function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change your interface to something like:

```
class Board
{
private:
    Ship *grid[10][10];
    bool hits[10][10];

public:
    Ship* getShip(int x, int y) const { return grid[x][y]; }
    Ship*& getShip(int x, int y) { return grid[x][y]; }

    bool getHit(int x, int y) const { return hits[x][y]; }
    bool& getHit(int x, int y) { return hits[x][y]; }
};
```

If you really want to return `grid` and `hits`, I recommend to use `std::array<std::array<Ship*, 10>, 10> grid;` (require C++11) instead of `Ship *grid[10][10];`.
if C++11 is not possible turn back to `std::vector`.

and then

```
private:
    std::array<std::array<Ship*, 10>, 10> grid;
public:
    const std::array<std::array<Ship*, 10>, 10>& getShips() const { return grid; }
    std::array<std::array<Ship*, 10>, 10>& getShips() { return grid; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure forcing C++11 for something this simple is the best route. Plus, the readability for this is extremely low.

Comment: @muppetjones: I prefer the C++11 version than `Ship* (&getShips())[10][10] { return grid; }`

Comment: I implemented this version of the Board class in my code. Could you possibly give me an example of how I would access and manipulate the grid array from within other functions? e.g  board.getShips()[x][y]=nullptr;

Comment: @Spielen: use it this way `board.getShip(x, y) = nullptr;` or ``board.getShip(x, y)->Draw(); /* Assuming a Draw method for Ship */``

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like getShips is returning the entire 10x10 array of `Ship*`-- you need to change what the `getShips` function is returning:

```
Ship*** getShips() { ...
```

However, I would recommend against mixing pointers and arrays. Pointers can be tricksy, and combining with arrays can get very difficult to debug. Instead, you could use all pointers: `Ship ***grid;` and initialize with new (I'll leave the initialization as an exercise, but here's a site that has an example: http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-arrays-in-c-using-new.html).

In reality, it might be better for the `Ship` class to store the indices of where it exists, perhaps something like this:

```
class Ship
{
   public:
      <<member func>>

   private:
      int nspaces_;
      int start_[2];
      int end_[2];
}
```

where you store the beginning index and the final index where the ship is found. You'll need to handle the code to identify the spaces between, but that is trivial. This setup would allow you to replace `Ship *grid[10][10]` with a single array of `Ship`s.

The `getShips` function would then become:

```
...
Ship ships_[<<number of ships>>];
Ship *getShips()
{
   return ships_;
}
...
```

and would be used:

```
board.getShips()[x][y]
```

Or...you could add a `getShip(int x, int y)` method.